# Reactjs onChange={handleInputChange} doesnt work

Tags: reactjs

Goodday !

Why is it the **handleInputChange** doenst work? did I miss something in my code?? I don't receive any error but **handleInputChange** didnt work.

This is my code

```
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});
  const [errMsg, setErrMsg] = useState({});

  const handleInputChange=(e)=>{
    let val = e.target.value;
    console.log(val)
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [e.target.name]: val
    });
  }

    <FormControl 
        variant="outlined" 
        fullWidth
        margin="normal">
          <InputLabel htmlFor="password-mask">Password</InputLabel>
          <OutlinedInput
            id="password-mask"
            type={valuespw.showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
            value={formData?.password}
            name="password"
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            endAdornment={
              <InputAdornment position="end">
                <IconButton
                  aria-label="masked password"
                  onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                  onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
                  edge="end"
                >
                  {valuespw.showPassword ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}
                </IconButton>
              </InputAdornment>
            }
            labelWidth={75}
          />
      </FormControl>
```

Comment: What is not working?  When you change the value, are you seeing the result of `console.log(val)` in the console?  What is `OutlinedInput`?

Comment: I didnt see the `console.log(val)`

Comment: Post your code for `OutlinedInput`, looks like your `onChange` prop is not being passed / not firing properly from within `OutlinedInput`

Comment: Could you put here whole content of component file? I mean including imports at the start of file. Cos it is impossible to figure out what kind of libraries do you use.

Comment: OutlinedInput is from @material-ui/core/OutlinedInput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a closure issue.  `setFormData` is wrapped inside `handleInputChange`, which is then wrapped in the `onChange` prop of `OutlinedInput`.  I wonder if you're never escaping the closure, which means your values will always be stale, never actually update, and never call the `onChange` handler of `OutlinedInput`. You can try a few things:

1. Use a callback within `setFormData` to make sure you are taking the latest value:

```js
 const handleInputChange=(e)=>{
    let val = e.target.value;
    console.log(val)
    setFormData(preValues => ({
      ...preValues,
      [e.target.name]: val
    }));
  }
```

2. Wrap `handleInputChange` in useCallback, to make sure it is giving fresh values every time the value changes:

```js
 const handleInputChange= React.useCallback((e) => {
    let val = e.target.value;
    console.log(val)
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [e.target.name]: val
    });
  }, [formData, setFormData])
```

At a cursory glance, these are things I would try.  If these don't help, try replicating the issue in a codesandbox, then post the reproducible issue here, and we can look and debug better.

Comment: I'd advice to use 1. makes a bit more sense. One more option is to use `useReducer`